# Export InfluxDB measurement to Pandas Dataframe with tags as it's own columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, influxdb

I'm rather new to Python and I have an InfluxDB query which I would like to set it to a pandas dataframe. However, the output seems to only include the measurements but not the tag values.

My code is shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient

def main():

    host = 'localhost'
    port = 8086
    user = 'abc'
    password = 'xyz'
    dbname = 'rain_rate'


    client = InfluxDBClient(host, port, user, password, dbname)
    print("Influx Connected")

    q = 'SELECT * FROM "rain_rate" WHERE time > now() - 24h GROUP BY "location", "site_id";'

    df = pd.DataFrame(client.query(q).get_points())
    print(df)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I print the dataframe, the output only shows the measurements and datapoints in columns but the tag values "location" and "site_id" are not in the dataframe.

How can I get the 2 tag values to be in the dataframe results as their own columns, together with the measurements?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose the query with `select * from` and make your actual query as a subquery.

Try this

```
'SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM "rain_rate" WHERE time > now() - 24h GROUP BY "location", "site_id");'
```

When you do this, the outer query converts all the tags into fields, so it will be converted to columns in the dataframe

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you so much!!